# Converting image out of memory error

Tags: c#

I have problem with my image converting program. I can convert 39 images and then coming this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in System.Drawing.dll

I don't figure out what is problem with my code.

error:

```
string[] originalImage = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text);
                foreach (var filename in originalImage)
                {

                    if (fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".JPG" || fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".PNG")
                    {
                        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename); //error coming here
                        //DefaultCompressionJpeg(bitmap);
                        string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

                        VariousQuality(bitmap, fn, fileExtension, fileOriginalDate);

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why do you even use a `for` loop if you're breaking out of it in the first loop?

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException` probably come from `FileStream` that might not properly disposed on every conversion process, thus existing instance still available in memory when creating new instance and used up memory space. `using` statement on `FileStream` may solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should dispose every object which implements IDisposable when you are done using that object. Following are some disposable objects in your program;

```
Filestream ms,
Bitmap original,
EncoderParameter encoderParameter
```

OutOfMemoryException is thrown when there is not enough memory to continue the execution of a program. Disposing above said objects should solve your problem.

**Update:**
Try the following code;

```
       if (fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".JPG" || fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".PNG")
        {
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename)) // added using statement.
            {
                //DefaultCompressionJpeg(bitmap);
                string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

                //saadame lisaks ka extensioni, et saaksime lihtsamini faili ümber nimetada
                VariousQuality(bitmap, fn, fileExtension, fileOriginalDate);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Updated my answer. I Included a using statement which will dispose your bitmap after it is used.

Comment: Apart from that, there are known issues with GDI+ which will show as OutOfMemoryException when they in fact are not, for example this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b813a2e-321b-46ae-9446-47d5b5a82eea/outofmemoryexception-in-drawimage-with-imageattributes?forum=netfxbcl&prof=required